# Codeigniter: Unable to access the Stylesheets

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following directory structure of Codeigniter Folder. You can see that I have put all my assets in the `assets` folder at the root of the application.

[image]

Base URL is defined as

> $config['base_url'] = 'http://kamran.dev/Codeigniter/application/';

I tried modify it to

> $config['base_url'] = 'http://kamran.dev/Codeigniter/';

but that didn't work either.

[image]

Can anyone please have a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

P.S. Then I removed the .htaccess file from the `application` folder that contains

> Deny From All

And this worked for me. But that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: I think this issue is also related to your other question...

Comment: You may say that. But that was more of an `htaccess` related so I put that in a separate one.

Comment: I think once you get the .htaccess access situated, change your `base_url` how I recommended it and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple options here. The easiest one is to move the assets folder to the same level as the application so that your directory structure is:

- application
- system
- assets

  - css
  - img
  - js

Because the assets folder is not in a folder with the .htaccess with `Deny From All` it won't be blocked by your web server.

Alternatively you can add an .htaccess file in the assets folder with the following rule:

```
# /assets/.htaccess
Allow from all
```

I haven't tested this but I think it should work.

Another option is to change the .htaccess and put an exception on the assets folder but it's a very bad idea (with security implications) to remove the `Deny From All` without writing alternate rules to lock all folders that shouldn't be accessible.

Also, set your `base_url` to the folder containing application, system and assets directories (this folder contains Codeigniter's bootstrap/front controller index.php).

Additionally, I would advise you to echo your urls using the base_url() function:

```
base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

OR to call a controller/route

```
base_url("controller/method");
```

The base_url function takes into account the value of `$config['index_page']` as well as the necessary leading/trailing slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `base_url` to the following:

```
echo base_url("assets/css/file-name-here.css");
```

You want to pass the URL string to the `base_url` function. This way, you can change `$config['base_url']` to whatever you want and it will append the string to that URL properly.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the answer of grim. If you have your rewrite engine on you should have the following in your root .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]  

</IfModule>
```