# Why CSS and JS are not loading?

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter

I have googled and tried many solutions which worked for others but not in my case. I don't know why.

**Background:**

I am learning to use CodeIgniter 2.2.0. I have set up project structure and all the things as below, but still I am not able to load my CSS and JS.

**View Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head id="Head1">
      <title>   </title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
      <!-- solution 1 I have tried: -->
      <!-- in below line I tried by using constant set in constants.php file under application/config/ folder --> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo (CSS.'dialog.css' );?>" type="text/css">
      <!-- solution 2 I have tried: -->
      <!-- As my css n script files are under CodeIgniter_2.2.0/assets/css and CodeIgniter_2.2.0/assets/scripts folder respectively -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/dialog.css" type="text/css">
      <!-- solution 3 I have tried -->
      <!-- This I tried by using autoload.php settings where I am setting autoload['helper'] = array('url'); -->
      <?php echo link_tag('assets/css/dailog.css');?> </br>
      <script src="../../script/Plugins/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   </head>
</html>
```

**Config**:

Also I have set

`$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/";` in `application/config/config.php` file.

**Project Folder Structure:**

My project folder structure is as follows :

[image]

(Application , System, Assets folders are at same level)

The contents of `.htaccess` file are :

(.htaccess file path : C:\xampp\htdocs.htaccess )

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|css|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

there are 2 more `.htaccess` file at `C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_2.2.0\System` and `C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_2.2.0\application` folder
both have single line written :

```
Deny from all
```

---

Also, at `C:\xampp\htdocs\`, there is a file `index.php` which is same as the `index.php` file placed at 
`C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_2.2.0\` in which I have set following things

```
$system_path = 'CodeIgniter_2.2.0/system';
$application_folder = 'CodeIgniter_2.2.0/application';
```

Is there anything that I am missing in this? I am not able to load any CSS or JS files on my page.

Comment: Is it possibly relevant that one instance your CSS files is named `dialog` and then the other two instances are `dailog`? Is this supposed to be the same file, or do you have multiple CSS files here?

Comment: I've answered a question that might be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201362/codeigniter-unable-to-access-the-stylesheets/19204480#19204480

Comment: What message are you getting in your browser for the files you are loading? 404? Also could you show what your three attempted solutions returned in the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution : just make changes in `.htaccess` at root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

n its working. :)