# Timepicker jquery scripts wont load in code igniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a problem with a simple jQuery time picker in codeigniter. The time picker works if i create it in a html test page outside codeigniter, but when loaded inside one of the codeigniter views it doesn't work. Is there a special way i should setup codeigniter before i can start using these type of widgets? here is the test page in which the time picker works. The scripts and styles are stored in local folders. I am trying to apply the same code in a codeigniter view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
        <script> 
            jQuery('#fromB').datetimepicker({
                datepicker:false,
                format:'H:i',
                step: 15
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id ="fromB" type="text" name="fromB"  />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any 404 messages in your console?
Where are the plugin's files? In your `application` folder?
If you get a 404: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201362/codeigniter-unable-to-access-the-stylesheets/19204480#19204480

Answer (score 0):

I use [bootstrap-datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/):

1. Include base_url in js path:

   ```
   <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') ?>"></script>
   ```
2. Call datepicker via javascript:

   ```
   <script>
   $(function() {
   $('.datepicker').datepicker({ format : 'dd-mm-yyyy', weekStart: 1 });
   });
   </script>
   ```
3. In my view:

   ```
   <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" />
   ```
4. **EDITED**:
   I have test your code in my codeigniter installation and I find the problem: If I include the javascript function `$(function() {  });` your code works.

Comment: Yes, i have tried that and it does not work. :((( Are there any specific configurations to codeigniter that need to be implemented?

Comment: Still not working... I think there is a problem with my codeigniter settings. The interesting thing is when loaded on html test pages outside the codeigniter application, these scripts work.

Comment: I just wanted to add that when using Codeigniter it's best practice to load assets using `base_url` just like @fructurj did.

Comment: i have tried the edited answers and it still fails to load. All of the scripts i have tried work if there is no codeigniter present. :(